# Find the two most similar values in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I have an array of integers and I want to find the two most similar values (least difference).

Example:
 if the values in the array are `80,100,500,600,501,505`, The two most similar values are `500` and `501`. How can I do this?

Comment: no is it not. I'm a german and we have holday now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to this problem is sorting the array first. This will make it so you only need to compare numbers that are adjacent to each other; selecting the 2 that have the smallest difference.

psuedocode:

```
sort the array: use Arrays.sort()
 int max_difference = Integer.MAXVALUE
int val1, val2;
for(i=0; i< array_size -1; ++i) {
 int x = array[i+1] - array[i];
 if(x <= max_difference) {
   max_difference = x;
   val1 = array[i];
   val2 = array[i+1];
 }
}
```

at the end, `val1` and `val2` will contain the 2 most similiar values.

Answer (score 4):

That seems small task, we can solve this problem as:

1: Apply any efficient **sorting** algorithm.

2:Then compare **adjacent element** and pick up whose **difference** is less.

code is here:

```
void nearestFinder(){
   int array[];
//apply  sorting algorithm - say selection sort
pre_diff = 0;
new_array = selection_sort(array);
   for(int i =0;i<new_array.length();i++){
      diff = Math.abs(new_array[i]-new_array[i+1]);
      if(diff>pre_diff){
       index =i;
       pre_diff =diff;
       }

      }
print(new_array[index],new_array[index+1])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you sort the data, the time complexity is O(N * ln(N))

```
int[] ints = {80, 100, 500, 600, 501, 505};
Arrays.sort(ints);
int value = 0, delta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length - 1; i++) {
    int d = ints[i + 1] - ints[i];
    if (d < delta) {
        delta = d;
        value = ints[i];
    }
}
System.out.printf("value " + value + " and " + (value + delta));
```

prints

```
value 500 and 501
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through each element O(N^2). To find the two most similar elements use subtraction and compare the difference with a stored lowest difference. Then once the lowest difference is found (ignoring the number in question you are searching for) you can also store the number you are searching with and the one you subtracted it from. You should also use absolute value so that the magnitude of the number is what you are comaring.

Comment: sorting the array first can take the O(n^2) down to O(nlgn)+O(n) = O(nlgn)

Comment: thank you all. It is so easy if you use array.sort first. How could I forgett about array.sort